# Undoing my working directory preserving my commit

Tags: git, commit, git-reset

This could be a very simple question. I commited my work, then I launched a find and replace script but I want to undo it, so to let my work go down to the actual commit. What is the right command to do that : I know about git reset soft/hard or git amend but it is not appropriate

Comment: Why is git reset --hard not appropriate?

Comment: Why is `git reset --hard HEAD` not appropriate? It ditches all your modifications, leaving you at the state of `HEAD`.

Comment: @MichaelWild I thought git reset--hard would undo the current commit, no ?

Comment: No, `git reset --hard HEAD^` does (notice the carret).

Comment: ah ok thanks I didn't notice !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

As the comments state `git reset --hard` will bring everything back.

But if you want to keep some of the files modified then doing:

```
git checkout -- <filename>
```

Will undo individual files.

Comment: Ouah, I put git reset --hard, I indeed went to my last commit but all the modifications I commited disappear. I don't know what screwed up, is oit possible to find the history of files including what they were after git reset --hard

Comment: Git reset --hard undoes all your changes.  If you did not commit the changes, there is no way to see them. http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html